# glade error on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, glade

What could this be?

```
[gimenero@PCSISING-ASU46 glade-3.10.2]$ glade.exe
GladeUI-Message: No displayable values for property GtkMessageDialog::message-type
GladeUI-Message: No displayable values for property GtkTreeSelection::mode
GladeUI-Message: 14 missing displayable value for GtkCellRendererAccel::accel-mods
      1 [main] glade 2508 exception::handle: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
    730 [main] glade 2508 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to  glade.exe.stackdump
      1 [main] glade 2636 exception::handle: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
    544 [main] glade 2636 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to glade.exe.stackdump
      1 [main] glade 6180 exception::handle: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
   1311 [main] glade 6180 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to glade.exe.stackdump
      1 [main] glade 5300 exception::handle: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
    925 [main] glade 5300 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to glade.exe.stackdump
      1 [main] glade 5108 exception::handle: Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
    868 [main] glade 5108 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to glade.exe.stackdump
Failed to connect to socket /tmp/fam-gimenero/fam-

(glade:3808): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: FAMOpen failed, FAMErrno=3

[gimenero@PCSISING-ASU46 glade-3.10.2]$ cat glade.exe.stackdump
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=6102048B
eax=00D200F8 ebx=61249DCC ecx=755C0F81 edx=006E9FE8 esi=00000000 edi=0028F9F4
ebp=61020C00 esp=0028C7C4 program=C:\cygwin\usr\local\bin\glade.exe, pid 4444, thread main
cs=0023 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
End of stack trace
```

I'm on cygwin 1.7.9, on Windows 7.

Comment: Where did `glade.exe` come from?

Comment: I compiled it from source. Called .configure with no args.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it:

http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2008/11/26/cygwin-upgrades-and-rebaseall/

```
kill all cygwin processes, then:

cd \cygwin\bin
ash
PATH=. rebaseall -v
```